# Detect when an element's nodeName changes and execute function

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, mutation-observers

I have an element `id_('example1')` that first exists as a placeholder element and is eventually replaced with an `iframe` with the same `id` value.

How do I run a simple function when the `nodeName` changes?

I've looked in to two different approaches:

1. `Promise`, something like (this doesn't work) `new Promise(id_('example1').nodeName == 'iframe').then(function {alert('okay now do something.');});`.
2. `MutationObserver` however I [couldn't find anything](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe) about observing the `nodeName` property.

I'll keep messing around with JavaScript `Promise` as I'm sure I'm getting the syntax wrong though I would be curious if I could determine a way to use a `MutationObserver`.

- Either way works fine.
- Absolutely no frameworks or libraries.

Comment: `nodeName` never changes, it's read-only so apparently the element is simply replaced by another one, which you can observe on its parent element using `childList: true` config.

Comment: @wOxxOm Nice, I'll look in to that now.

Comment: "eventually replaced" must take place somewhere. Can't you modify that part of the code to run the code there?

Comment: You could still do 
`const oldPaymentCode = paymentCode; paymentCode = function() { oldPaymentCode(); alert("Okay, now do something") }`